# Groovy string replace add new line

Tags: groovy

Got a groovy script that is pulling some text from a soap connection and I am trying to add a bullet point before any bullet points. Here is the code I have but it does not work and it may never work, but thought I would ask.

```
td (it.@detail.toString().replaceAll('&gt;', '>').replaceAll("•", "\n •"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work.

ie, try:

```
println it.@detail.toString().replaceAll('&gt;', '>').replaceAll("•", "\n •")
```

To see it working in the console output.

I guess you're viewing this in HTML with a browser?

Newlines don't appear in HTML normally, so you'd need to  wrap the text in a `<pre>` tag.

Assuming this is with StreamingMarkupBuilder or similar, try:

```
td {
    pre( it.@detail.toString().replaceAll('&gt;', '>').replaceAll("•", "\n •") )
}
```

Comment: Made the changes that you stated for seeing this in an html browser and all it did was add the pre tags as text instead of actual pre tags.

Comment: @jrock2004 is this using the markupbuilder?  You don't specify :-(

Comment: @jrock2004 Updated my answer with a SMB example at the bottom :-)